# In JBoss 4.2.3 is there any way to change the order that EARDeployer loads/deploys the various .ear files?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ear

I have 3 ear files and I want to control the order they are loaded. Any configuration that I can do to achieve this? (no, I don't want to rename my ears 1.ear 2.ear, etc...)

Comment: I don't think so, no, it's always alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the section [Deployment Sorter](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringTheDeploymentScannerInConfjbossSystemxml)
 you can choose between EnhancedSuffixOrder and PrefixDeploymentOrder.